# Photoswipe and jQuery error when setting caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to grab the caption from a rel attribute of the target element of photoswipe using the following method:

```
$("#fgallery a").photoSwipe({ getImageCaption: $(this).attr("rel") });
```

However I get a jQuery error.
Has anyone tried that??
Do you know what's wrong??

A running version of the gallery can be found here: [dolihos](http://www.dolihos.gr/wp/90/erga/ktiriaka/politismos/ktirio-ekdiloseon-dimou-mistra/)
However I'm not using the code abover since it throws an error but everyting else is the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution when using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="fgallery">
    <a href="fullurl.jpg" title="caption" rel="caption">
       <img src="smallimage.jpg" alt="caption" title="caption" />
    </a>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
// this will return the a-elements rel as caption
$("#fgallery a").photoSwipe({ 
    getImageCaption: function(item) {return $(item).attr('rel'); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the plugin here https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe it seems that `getImageCaption` requires a function passed to it, rather than a variable.

Try changing it to this (untested):

```
$("#fgallery a").photoSwipe({ 
    getImageCaption: function() {return $(this).attr("rel"); }
});
```